# Loopback is returning only 1 record?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Code:
[image]
I have this loopback query

This returns only 1 record however if I run the following MySQL query I get 2
 Which is leading to possible data loss in my app.

```sql
select r.id, r.name, rdm.distributor_specific_retailer_code from retailer r left join address on address.id = r.fk_id_address left join  retailer_distributor_mapping rdm on r.id = rdm.fk_id_retailer where rdm.fk_id_distributor = 2 and rdm.is_active = 1 and r.id in (2)
```

2 results from SQL query and 1 from loopback find.

Comment: Maybe your `limit` is 1 instead of at least 2? Or maybe your `offset` is 1 instead of 0, skipping the first result? We don't see your values here.

Comment: Also please edit your question to have the code as actual code and not an image. ([Why?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode))

Answer (score 1):

check your result type of find, it should be array
then run your find method without limit and offset (I can't see what value they have) then test it again.

also you can simply add your own method to Retail model and execute a raw query.
in common\models\Retailer.js file
create your own method:

```
Retailer.myMethod = function (args, cb) {

        var ds = Retailer.dataSource;
        var sql = "your raw query goes here";

        ds.connector.query(sql, args, function (err, data) {

            if (err) console.error(err);

            cb(err, data);

        });

    };
```